# stationary Markov chain without starting in stationary distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

What would be a concrete example (i.e. the transition Matrix $P$) for a discrete time stationary Markov chain, i.e. $(X(t_{1}+t),t_{2}+t),...,t_{n}+t))$ does not depend on $t$, $\forall n\geq 1, \forall t_1,t_2,...,t_n$, that is not initialized with the stationary distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=1$ and $t_1=0$, the first condition reads that the distribution of $X(t)$ does not depend on $t$, in particular it implies that the Markov chain is at stationarity. In other words, what you are asking is impossible.